# Слово "исполняющий" в деловой переписке

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно? В обращении к адресату написано: "исполняющей обязанности Пагасянц Анне Ивановне...". Скажите, пожалуйста, слово "исполняющий" может употреблятся только в мужском роде в деловой переписке или и в женском тоже? Спасибо, Николаша.

Answer (score 1):

В официальных документах предпочтительна форма мужского рода.
Но запрета на форму женского рода нет.